# finding satisfied condition while debugging in pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a programme with a lot of if else conditions. A small sample is as follows:

```
if(lhs == 'a' and rhs=='a'): return 'aa'

if(lhs == 'i' and rhs=='i'): return 'ii'

if(lhs == 'u' and rhs=='u'): return 'uu'

else: return 'invalid'
```

I want to debug my programme so that I can find out which condition is satisfied. Where do I add such a breakpoint in pycharm so that I can find out which condition is invoked?

Comment: On a different note, why not do: `if lhs+rhs in ('aa', 'ii', 'uu'): return lhs+rhs else: ...`

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't also be using separate `if` clauses, as all the conditions will be checked

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thank you for the advice. However, I have to be flexible in my approach

Comment: I need multiple conditions depending on the position of the char in the str and also the end result is different each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't break in the middle of a line. Here are some alternative solutions:

1. Add the return statements in a new line. You'll have to add multiple breakpoints.
2. Move this code to a function, then you can see the returned value when  function call returns
3. Have a variable `ret='aa'`, assign to the variable after the if-else statement, then return `ret` at the end.